# Build wheel for a package (like scipy) lacking dependency declaration

Tags: python, scipy, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel

I think it doesn't make a difference here but I'm using Python 2.7.

So the general part of my question is the following: I use a separate `virtualenv` for each of my projects. I don't have administrator access and I don't want to mess with system-installed packages anyway. Naturally, I want to use wheels to speed up package upgrades and installations across the `virtualenv`s. How can I build a wheel whose dependencies are only met within a specific `virtualenv`?

Specifically, issuing

```
pip wheel -w $WHEELHOUSE scipy
```

fails with

```
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy
  Destination directory: /home/moritz/.pip/wheelhouse
  Complete output from command /home/moritz/.virtualenvs/base/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/moritz/.virtualenvs/base/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /home/moritz/.pip/wheelhouse:
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/moritz/.virtualenvs/base/build/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/home/moritz/.virtualenvs/base/build/scipy/setup.py", line 225, in setup_package

    from numpy.distutils.core import setup

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Cleaning up...
```

because `numpy` is not globally present and while building the wheel works when a `virtualenv` with `numpy` installed is active, it seems like a terrible idea to have the wheel depend on a specific `virtualenv`'s version of `numpy`.

`pandas` which also depends on `numpy` appears to install its own components of `numpy` but I'm not sure that's the best solution.

I could install `numpy` with `--user` and use that to build the `scipy` wheel. Are there better options?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Problem description

- Have a python package (like `scipy`), which is dependent on other packages (like `numpy`) but `setup.py` is not declaring that requirement/dependency.
- Building a wheel for such a package will succeed in case, current environment provides the package(s) which are needed.
- In case, required packages are not available, building a wheel will fail.

Note: Ideal solution is to correct the broken `setup.py` by adding there required package declaration. But this is mostly not feasible and we have to go another way around.

## Solution: Install required packages first

The procedure (for installing `scipy` which requires `numpy`) has two steps

1. build the wheels
2. use the wheels to install the package you need

### Populate wheelhouse with wheels you need

This has to be done only once and can be then reused many times.

1. have properly configured pip configuration so that installation from wheels is allowed, wheelhouse directory is set up and overlaps with `download-cache` and `find-links` as in following example of `pip.conf`:

   ```
   [global]
   download-cache = /home/javl/.pip/cache
   find-links = /home/javl/.pip/packages

   [install]
   use-wheel = yes

   [wheel]
   wheel-dir = /home/javl/.pip/packages
   ```
2. install all required system libraries for all the packages, which have to be compiled
3. build a wheel for required package (`numpy`)

   ```
   $ pip wheel numpy
   ```
4. set up virtualenv (needed only once), activate it and install there `numpy`:

   ```
   $ pip install numpy
   ```

   As a wheel is ready, it shall be quick.
5. build a wheel for `scipy` (still being in the virtualenv)

   ```
   $ pip wheel scipy
   ```

   By now, you will have your wheelhouse populated with wheels you need.
6. You can remove the temporary virtualenv, it is not needed any more.

### Installing into fresh virtualenv

I am assuming, you have created fresh virtualenv, activated it and wish to have `scipy` installed there.

Installing `scipy` from new `scipy` wheel directly would still fail on missing `numpy`. This we overcome by installing `numpy` first.

```
$ pip install numpy
```

And then finish with scipy

```
$ pip install scipy
```

I guess, this could be done in one call (but I did not test it)

```
$ pip install numpy scipy
```

## Repeatedly installing `scipy` of proven version

It is likely, that at one moment in future, new release of `scipy` or `numpy` will be released and pip will attempt to install the latest version for which there is no wheel in your wheelhouse.

If you can live with the versions you have used so far, you shall create `requirements.txt` stating the versions of `numpy` and `scipy` you like and install from it.

This shall ensure needed package to be present before it is really used.

Comment: My setup is pretty much as you describe it in the linked answer, however, what you write here isn't very clear to me. The `scipy` wheel simply cannot be built without satisfying the `numpy` dependency. It needs the C code in order to compile.

Comment: @Midnighter `scipy` seem to be quite complex solution which is not easy to install. I could be too quick in estimating, wheel could be build easily, currently I am trying to do so, but if I fail, I will remove or update my answer.

Comment: @Midnighter A note: wheel does not prevent compiling your package (like numpy), it only allows to do it once (by `pip wheel <package>`) and then install it quickly. If it is C-based package, it will require compilation, unless you have an egg to rebuild it into wheel.

Comment: @Midnighter I did it. Described in the answer.

Comment: So which `numpy` were you using to build the `scipy` wheel?

Comment: @Midnighter I did not select any version of numpy, it got selected automatically. And a wheel for numpy (version 1.8.1) got created automatically while I was building wheel for scipy (version 0.14.0). See list of wheels created today - I added this information to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56096/discussion-between-midnighter-and-jan-vlcinsky).

Comment: @Midnighter Answer shortened and updated. Small edits to your question were done too. Thanks to our chat I realized, I completely missed your important finding, that `scipy` is not declaring required packages. This made 50% of the solution.