# Installing mpi4py

Tags: linux, python-3.x, mpi4py

I am trying to install mpi4py in my Linux machine. I have recently installed anaconda 4.1.1 and according to their documentation the package is suppose to come with mpi4py 2.0.0. When I tried verifying with "`conda list`" I am not able to find the package in the list.

I have tried "`pip install mpi4py`" and I am getting an error like this "Failed building wheel for mpi4py" I had no luck with "`easy_install mpi4py`" as well.

Comment: Which specific OS do you have?...also can you paste your full terminal output when you try `pip install mpi4py`, please?

Answer (score 4):

When installing mpi4py, your MPI binaries has to be on the `PATH`. That is, if you type e.g. `which mpiexec` and nothing comes up, you have to run

```
export PATH="/path/to/mpi/bin:${PATH}"
```

Now `which mpiexec` should print the path of the MPI executable, and so `pip` and `conda` should be able to locate MPI.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a dependency. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353267/build-wheel-for-a-package-like-scipy-lacking-dependency-declaration)
for a possible explanation.