# Failed building wheel for atari-py

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying:

```
pip install atari-py
```

on Python 3.5 and I am getting:

> failed building wheel for atari-py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build wheel for a package (like scipy) lacking dependency declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353267/build-wheel-for-a-package-like-scipy-lacking-dependency-declaration)

Comment: Regarding " Populate wheelhouse with wheels you need " section in the link:
How to get into and adjust pip.conf  ?
How to activate virtualenv ?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Can you show more info?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using conda on Mac OS to build a python3.6 environment and I meet the same

```
failed building wheel for atari-py
```

Then I tried to find atari-py on here:

```
https://github.com/openai/atari-py
```

On this page it says:
Make sure you have cmake installed. On OSX, you probably want

```
brew install cmake.
```

Then after I install cmake and rebuild environment on my mac, there is no such fail anymore and the environment built success. Hope this will give you some hints!

Comment: I just installed cmake (Ubuntu 16.04), but it still doesn't work for me. Same error

Comment: I installed cmake (ubuntu 16.04), and it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Running ubuntu and didn't have cmake installed.

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding " Populate wheelhouse with wheels you need " section in the
>   link: How to get into and adjust pip.conf ? How to activate virtualenv
>   ?

Per-user:

- On Unix the default configuration file is: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`
  which respects the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable.
- On macOS the configuration file is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf`.
- On Windows the configuration file is `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`.

Inside a virtualenv:

```
On Unix and macOS the file is `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`
On Windows the file is: `%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini`
```

To edit it you could use your favorite text editor. You could find more info in: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=pip.conf

Here another answer that could help you guiding (there is a complete faq to install some packages): [Build wheel for a package (like scipy) lacking dependency declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353267/build-wheel-for-a-package-like-scipy-lacking-dependency-declaration)

And to understand & work with **virtualenv**, you should read: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Hope this helps! Good luck!