# pip building wheel fails for pycddlib

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pip

I am having severe problems installing pycddlib for Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

- The package can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycddlib/#downloads). However there is no wheel for Python 3.6 and hence the provided wheels to not support my system.
- I followed the instructions on this [site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/) to build a wheel. I tried to install *Visual C++ Build Tools 2015* however I had no sucess in installing the package as pip install pycddlib  throws the error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

- Instead I installed Visual Studio 2017 with Python development workload and the Native development tools option. Trying to install pycddlib  now does not throw the same error but simply the following error

  ```
    Failed building wheel for pycddlib
  ```
- This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353267/build-wheel-for-a-package-like-scipy-lacking-dependency-declaration) suggests that one has to install required packages first, but pycddlib does not seem to require anything else
- This [website](https://searchcode.com/file/110198560/appveyor.yml) suggests building instructions for the package pycddlib. Nonetheless I am lacking knowledge to update theses instructions in order to build the correct thing for my setup.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here the first link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353267/build-wheel-for-a-package-like-scipy-lacking-dependency-declaration

Comment: Here the second link https://searchcode.com/file/110198560/appveyor.yml

Comment: I edited the links into your question. But the second link ` followed the instructions on this site` is empty - where do you want to link this to?

Comment: thanks I added the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer has added support for python 3.6. Hence there are working wheels for Python 3.6 under [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycddlib/#downloads) available now.